# Can't save the value of textbox when i close the form and reopen it again

Tags: ms-access

Help please
I wanna keep my textbox value displayed when i close the form and reopen it again in microsoft access
I tried various solutions but all failed whether macro or vba codes in microsoft access i appreciate your support

Default value property

Answer (score 1):

You can use *TempVars* for this and a little code behind your form that stores and restores the value entered.

So, if your textbox is named *Textbox1*:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me!Textbox1.Value = TempVars("Textbox1").Value

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    TempVars("Textbox1").Value = Me!Textbox1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it not worked yet :( :(

Comment: Try again. It is tested and works here.

Comment: (me) not activated as a blue colour as you show, it is written with me as a normal text

Comment: Yes. The VB editor uses another colour set.